# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException : no qualifying bean of type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, repository, javabeans

I get this error when call my GET request (modes-calcul) and I don't understand why... My dependency injection is correct?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.margaux.margaux.repository.ModeCalculDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

ModeCalculController :

```
@Slf4j
@Transactional
@RestController
@RequestMapping("modes-calcul")
public class ModeCalculController {
    private ModeCalculService modeCalculService;

    @Autowired
    public ModeCalculController(ModeCalculService modeCalculService) {
        this.modeCalculService = modeCalculService;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<List<ModeCalculDTO>> getModesCalcul() {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<ModeCalculDTO>>(modeCalculService.getModesCalcul(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

ModeCalculServiceImpl :

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@Transactional
public class ModeCalculServiceImpl implements ModeCalculService {
    private ModeCalculDAO modeCalculDAO;

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    public ModeCalculImpl(ModeCalculDAO modeCalculDAO){
        this.modeCalculDAO = modeCalculDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ModeCalculDTO> getModesCalcul() {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        List<ModeCalcul> modesCalcul = modeCalculDAO.findAll();

        return modesCalcul
                .stream()
                .map(modeCalcul -> mapper.map(modeCalcul, ModeCalculDTO.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

ModeCalculDAO :

```
@Repository
public interface ModeCalculDAO extends JpaRepository<ModeCalcul, Long> {
}
```

Thanks for your help..

Comment: I couldn't see any mistake in your code, let me know if you fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

check whether the ModeCalculDAO is in sub package of main program
or if it is not a sub package try to add @ComponentScan(package name) in main program

Comment: the tree is like this. what do you want me to put in the component scan? and where? https://www.casimages.com/i/21011512585977403.png.html

Answer (score 0):

When you run your application it scans all the files which are inside the sub package of the project main package in which your main class has defined using @SpringBootApplication. So put all the files inside the sub package of your main class that you want to scan or if your package is not a subpackage of your main package use @ComponentScan(your_package name) at your main class.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `MargauxApplication` class to be inside `com.margaux.margaux` package.

Can you please share `MargauxApplication` class to check its import packages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the MargauxApplication class :

```
package com.margaux.margaux;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MargauxApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MargauxApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I tried to put `@ComponentScan("com.margaux.margaux")` or `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.margaux.margaux")`
in this class but it doesn't work.
My other classes have this :

```
package com.margaux.margaux.repository;
package com.margaux.margaux.service;
etc ...
```

in my pom I have this:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

if I put this, it works :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Why ?